# Using duplicate and if_else to mark all involved rows in third column

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

Now I want to see in all duplicates values in col of "mappedTerm" given the group by each var across the different datasets. If there are duplicates value, then mark as "yes" in new col.

My code is like this:

```
vm_check<-vm %>%
  filter(mappedTerm!=":::UNDEF:::")%>%
  group_by(var)%>%
  mutate(rep=if_else(duplicated(mappedTerm), "yes", ""))
```

But the problem is that it only marks "yes" for rest of cols not the first col. Like:

```
var1.  var2.  var3. rep
xxx.   abc.   df1.
xxx.   abc.   df2.   yes
xxx.   abc.   df3.   yes
```

instead:

```
var1.  var2.  var3. rep
xxx.   abc.   df1.   yes
xxx.   abc.   df2.   yes
xxx.   abc.   df3.   yes
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I get the rep=yes for all duplicates rows instead of the rows with "yes" but for first row?
2. Any better solution to get the desired output as I mentioned at begin?(*Output for all duplicates values in col of "mappedTerm" given the group_by each var across the different datasets*)

Thanks a lot for your help~~!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You want to group by `mappedTerm` and then see which groups have more than one row?

Comment: @SamR what I want to do is that: group by var, and see whether the mappedTerm has the same value within each var. Bc the data was collected from different datasets at different time (repeated measure), so I also need to see whether the same value across the different datasets. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that your sample data has any rows where `mappedTerm` is duplicated in a `var` group. But the issue you are facing is almost certainly because of how `duplicated()` works.

Try this:

```r
vec  <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
duplicated(vec)
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Note that the first time each value it appears, R has not seen it before so it is not considered duplicated. We can address this by running `duplicated()` backwards:

```r
duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE)
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Of course, the issue now is that the last item is not considered duplicated.

Putting it all together, we can do:

```r
duplicated(vec) | duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE)
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In your case, assuming your data is `dat`, we can do:

```r
dat  |>
    filter(mappedTerm!=":::UNDEF:::")  |>
    group_by(var)  |>
    mutate(
        rep = ifelse(
            (duplicated(mappedTerm) | duplicated(mappedTerm, fromLast = TRUE)), 
            "yes", 
            ""
        )
    )
```

However, I would prefer to test whether the number of distinct `mappedTerm` values are greater than the total rows per group:

```r
dat  |>
    filter(mappedTerm!=":::UNDEF:::")  |>
    group_by(var)  |>
    mutate(
        rep = n_distinct(mappedTerm) < n()  
    )
```

This will give you a `TRUE` value every time there is more than one `mappedTerm` per group, otherwise it will be `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explicit explanation~~! That really helps me to understand the situation I had. Yeah, the sample dataset was not a good example, it is too small to contain replicated values. I just updated that. Thanks again~~!

Answer (score 1):

There are no duplicates of `mappedTerm` within each `var` with the dataset you provided, so maybe I did not understand your question entirely. If there are duplicates, and I understood your question correctly, then this should work:

```r
library(dplyr)
vm_check <-vm %>%
  filter(mappedTerm!=":::UNDEF:::")%>%
  group_by(var, mappedTerm) %>%
  mutate(rep=if_else(n()>1, "yes", ""))
```

It checks for number of rows for each group of `var` and `mappedTerm`. If there are duplicates, this number is `>1`

edit: or, alternatively, this will return a logical vector, which returns TRUE if there is a duplicate:

```r
vm_check <-vm %>%
  filter(mappedTerm!=":::UNDEF:::")%>%
  group_by(var, mappedTerm) %>%
  mutate(rep=n()>1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Leon Samson, yes, i realized the sample dataset i provided here is bad, it is too small to contain duplicated values as example. i updated the dataset to 200 rows, and tried your solution, it works for my first question. Thanks~~~!